# Error on running Visual Studio Basic Library(Android, Gradle)

Tags: java, android

apologies complete newbie.

Opening 'Basic Library(Android, Gradle) as a new project in Visual Studio 2022 and simply run the Hello World app and I get the following error 'straight out of the box'.

"MSB3073    The command "gradlew.bat -p "Drive:\xxxx\xxxxx\test4\app"  assemblex86Debug" exited with code 1."

Any Ideas please?

Rob